# How to correct provide web pack for my symfony project in docker?

Tags: docker, symfony, webpack

I have app with Symfony5 and I need to applu web pack to my app. For that I enter in php-fpm container and follow instruction:

```
composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle
yarn install
yarn: not found
```

how to correct provide web pack for my app ?

docker compose:

```
    php:
        container_name: php-fpm
        build: ./php-fpm
        ports:
            - "9000:9001"
        environment: # You can use this section to set environment variables. But you can also use the .env file.
            - MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN=${MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN} # AMQP connection string-
        volumes:
            - ./symfony:/var/www/symfony:cached
            - ./logs/symfony:/var/www/symfony/var/log:cached
        links:
            - redis
        depends_on: 
            - db
        networks:
            - php
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.10

LABEL maintainer="Vincent Composieux <vincent.composieux@gmail.com>"

RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
    coreutils \
    php7-fpm \
    php7-apcu \
    php7-ctype \
    php7-curl \
    php7-dom \
    php7-gd \
    php7-iconv \
    php7-imagick \
    php7-json \
    php7-intl \
    php7-mcrypt \
    php7-fileinfo\
    php7-mbstring \
    php7-opcache \
    php7-openssl \
    php7-pdo \
    php7-pdo_mysql \
    php7-mysqli \
    php7-pdo_pgsql \
    php7-pgsql \
    php7-xml \
    php7-zlib \
    php7-phar \
    php7-tokenizer \
    php7-session \
    php7-simplexml \
    php7-xdebug \
    php7-zip \
    php7-xmlwriter \
    make \
    curl \
    zlib-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    rabbitmq-c-dev \
    oniguruma-dev \
    php7-pecl-amqp \
    php7-amqp \
    php7-redis

RUN echo "$(curl -sS https://composer.github.io/installer.sig) -" > composer-setup.php.sig \
        && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | tee composer-setup.php | sha384sum -c composer-setup.php.sig \
        && php composer-setup.php && rm composer-setup.php* \
        && chmod +x composer.phar && mv composer.phar /usr/bin/composer

COPY symfony.ini /etc/php7/conf.d/
COPY symfony.ini /etc/php7/cli/conf.d/
COPY xdebug.ini  /etc/php7/conf.d/

COPY symfony.pool.conf /etc/php7/php-fpm.d/

CMD ["php-fpm7", "-F"]

WORKDIR /var/www/symfony
EXPOSE 9001
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install yarn, replace the following in your Dockerfile:

```
RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
    coreutils \
    ...
```

with

```
RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
    coreutils \
    yarn \
    ...
```